# Multi validator of class-validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I use `class-validator` for my `Nestjs`.

I have an DTO:

```
export default class CatDto extends BaseDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @IsNumber()
  @Expose()
  age: number;
}
```

The `age` can be a `@IsNumber()` or a `@IsNumberString()`.

Both `10` and `'10'` is valid.

Can I do that?.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently an open issue in class-validator package itself. That's why I think you should implement your own custom validator, you can find such a custom validator to validate multi types in here: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/160

And here's the example of custom validator that could validate multiple types:

```
const typeValidator = {
    "string": function (value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const validator = new Validator();
        return validator.isString(value);
    },
    "int": function (value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const validator = new Validator();
        return validator.isInt(value);
    }
};

export function IsType(types: (keyof (typeof typeValidator))[], validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: "wrongType",
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
                    return types.some(v => typeValidator[v](value, args));
                },
                defaultMessage(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments) {
                    const lastType = types.pop();
                    if (types.length == 0)
                        return `Has to be ${lastType}`;
                    return `Can only be ${types.join(", ")} or ${lastType}.`;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

And then you can implement the code above to your code like:

```
export default class CatDto extends BaseDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @IsType(["string", "int"])
  @Expose()
  age: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsNumberString, ValidateIf } from 'class-validator';

export class MyDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @ValidateIf((object, value) => typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number')
  @IsNumberString()
  age: string | number;
}
```

You can do something like this to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using class-transformer

```
import { Type } from "class-transformer";

export default class CatDto extends BaseDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @IsNumber()
  @Expose()
  @Type(() => Number)
  age: number;
}
```